# Can the linked-open-data lose its synonym to open data?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I see that the [linked-open-data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linked-open-data) tag is marked as a synonym to [open-data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-data), but I think that is a mistake.

Whilst the term does have the words `open` and `data`, questions on linked open data are not, I think, requests for data that is open, but rather on how to process [linked data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_data) which is open.  Think semantic web, OWL, TTL, RDF, GeoSPARQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have removed that synonymy.

There is only one question tagged with it, so my preference would be to simply remove/replace that tag rather than creating a tag wiki for it.